# Три знака препинания подряд

Tags: пунктуация

**Интересно, что предложение - и твое необычное, в частности! -, написанное мною без всего лишь одно знака препинания, претендует на двусмысленность.**

Могут ли быть так расставлены знаки? Насколько я понял, конструкция " - и твое необычное, в частности!-" имеет характер вводного предложения.

Answer (score 4):

Нет. Восклицательный знак внутри предложения нормативно может быть только перед закрывающей кавычкой или скобкой. *Есть одно "полуисключение", вернее - орфографический казус, когда два правила вступают в противоречие, там иногда приходится идти на нарушение этого принципа, но это не наш случай*.

В вашем случае я бы или пожертвовал восклицанием, или заменил тире скобками.

Answer (score 1):

> и твое необычное, в частности

Эта фраза похожа на попутное замечание. А оно обычно заключается в скобки, т.к. не несёт особой смысловой нагрузки.